# Add a 2000ms delay to the following javascript

Tags: javascript, delay

I need to add a 2000ms delay to the following javascript. How do I do so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container_main").hide();
});
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#container_main").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to add a 2000ms delay... erm? where? between what?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ YOUR_CODE_HERE },2000);`

Comment: use can use setTimeOut

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#container_main").hide();
    });

Comment: How do I add SetTimeOut to $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container_main").hide();
});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Here you can put  delay in ms(in following i have put 3000)

```
   var temp1=setInterval(function(){$("#div1").show();},3000);
```

Then you can clear it using . In case you don't  clear it will keep executing after every 3000 ms.

```
clearInterval(temp1);
```

Ex:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var temp1 = setInterval(function() {
        $("#container_main").hide();
        clearInterval(temp1);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I need the completed code.

Comment: tell me where u want to put the delay in hide or show ...??

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container_main").hide();
});

Comment: Why `setInterval` and not `setTimeout`?

Comment: setInterval didn't work for me.